# One signal create a new Ios User every time

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, onesignal

[image]Every time I launch my app One signal create a new Ios User no matter if its the same device. This is not happen in Android only in Ios.

This is a pic of OneSignal Users, all Iphone5,3 is a only device.

I init one signal with this code in app.components.ts:

```
window["plugins"].OneSignal
        .startInit("MyID", "MyIDOne")
        .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
        .endInit();
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an MCVE of the problem along with the steps you've taken so far to fix the problem. This will help exclude troubleshooting paths that will not work.

Comment: But i dont use code for de user registration, the onesignal make it.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen except in some cases where you delete the app from your device and re-install it. If this is happening in another case, then there is either a problem with the version of the OneSignal SDK you are using, or with the way it has been integrated into your application.

Based on the limited details here I'm not sure how to resolve this. I recommend getting in touch with the OneSignal support team and sending a copy of the code you are using to initialize OneSignal to help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: So this is happen when i reinstall the app? I add the code for initialize one signal.

Comment: @DanielaRomero When you will delete application and reinstall it. The device Token will be changed and this will create a new user on OneSignal. This is the standard approach. If you want to have one device against one email/userID then you can set them as tags in OneSignal